Using JS Stack Navigator with expo-router
The documentation explains how to create the Navigator, but it doesn't show how to add Screens.  I try to use jsStack.Screen but it doesn't work, I get the confusing error Error: A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children (found 'Screen' for the screen 'posts/index'). To render this component in the navigator, pass it in the 'component' prop to 'Screen'. - but passing the component prop goes against expo-router file navigation system
app/_layout.tsx
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { withLayoutContext, Stack } from 'expo-router'
import { ParamListBase, StackNavigationState } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  StackNavigationEventMap,
  StackNavigationOptions
} from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { NavigationBar } from '@/components'
import { Provider } from '@/provider'

import Places from './places'

const { Navigator } = createStackNavigator()

const JsStack = withLayoutContext<
  StackNavigationOptions,
  typeof Navigator,
  StackNavigationState<ParamListBase>,
  StackNavigationEventMap
>(Navigator)

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <JsStack
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown: false
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen name="posts/index" />
            <Stack.Screen name="posts/[id]" />
          </JsStack>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </View>
    </Provider>
  )
}

